# How to retrieve embedded video code in sharepoint 2013 library in javascript

Tags: sharepoint, youtube, sharepoint-2013, flexslider

I have uploaded youtube video in SharePoint 2013 library using embedded code. Video got uploaded. But Now I have to show the same video in flexslider, for which I require the 11 character code. But I couldn't find the code in any of the SP library columns.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Using the RESTful api you can get it like this:

```
<site>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<YourAssetLibrary>')/items?$select=VideoSetEmbedCode
```